# Data Explorer displays incorrect hour for PM timestamps

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, timestamps

While fact-checking [this timestamp-related feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59343/should-absolute-timestamps-have-leading-zero-on-hours), I noticed that timestamps in the Data Explorer are displayed with hours in 12-hour format, even though no AM/PM is displayed. So `2009-01-01 01:00:00` could be 1:00 AM or 1:00 PM. See [this sample query](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/8841/):

```
select top 200 creationdate, datepart(hh, creationdate) as hour
from users
where datepart(yyyy, creationdate) = 2009
order by creationdate​
```

And the result:

http://img832.imageshack.us/img832/209/dataexplorertimestamps.png

Note that the time is actually stored correctly internally, as ordering works correctly, and the DatePart function works correctly. I've verified that this occurs for Users.CreationDate, Comments.CreationDate, and Posts.CreationDate. I'm guessing it happens on every timestamp field.

Comment: Patch anyone :) ?

Comment: @waffles: Is it an environment problem, or a code problem? We can only fix the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this isn't exactly a bug, but it definitely needs to be resolved.

Here's a simplified query that demonstrates the problem:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(datetime, 'Jan 1 2010 1:00 AM'),
    CONVERT(datetime, 'Jan 1 2010 1:00 PM')
```

The resulting output is:

```
------------------- ------------------- 
2010-01-01 01:00:00 2010-01-01 01:00:00 

(1 row(s) affected)
```

which is clearly not good.

Looking at the source code (App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Helpers/QueryResults.cs:172), it appears that for date types, all that's happening for display is calling `.ToString()` on the object. So it may be that the system locale is set up with a weird date format.

I'm not familiar with the Azure platform, but this can be fixed by either (a) fixing the system locale settings (probably a good idea anyway if possible), or (b) explicitly specifying a format string with all the required date/time components.

Comment: i would say it's a bug if it is displaying in 12-hour format without displaying am/pm, as there's no way of knowing what "01:00:00" is, and nothing to indicate that it should be interpreted as anything other than 1:00 AM.

Comment: @Kip: Agreed, it's definitely showing the wrong value, whatever word we use to describe the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed in latest, should be deployed shortly:

```
col = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss");
```